# Calling "ps" command with arguments with execl has unexpected behaviour

Tags: c, bash, execl

I wrote a simple C program that uses the execl function. What I'm expecting to see after running this program is the output of `ps -U myusername`.

If writing `ps -U myusername` in terminal, I get the desired result.

If calling `execl("/bin/ps", "/bin/ps", "-U myusername", NULL)` I get the following error message `error: improper list`.

However, if I remove the space from `-U myusername`, and call the function in the following way: `execl("/bin/ps", "/bin/ps", "-Umyusername", NULL)`, I get the correct result.

Why is this happening and how can I achieve the expected behaviour (this is just a simple example; what I actually want is to let the user input the command and split it in command and arguments and finally call something like `execlp("command", "command", "arguments", NULL)`.)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a variadic function. Just call it like this :

```
execlp("command", "command", "first arg", "second arg" /*, etc*/, NULL);
```

or in your case

```
execlp("/bin/ps", "/bin/ps", "-U", "username", NULL);
```

The `NULL` says to the function : "it is ok, there are no more arguments." If you forget it, there is an undefined behavior.

To go further : http://manpagesfr.free.fr/man/man3/stdarg.3.html

The line `execlp("/bin/ps", "/bin/ps", "-Uusername", NULL);` works because `ps -Uusername` is the same as `ps -U username`. Just type it in the console, it will prove you that fact ;)

The line `execlp("/bin/ps", "/bin/ps", "-U username", NULL);` does not work because it is as if you type `ps '-U username'` in your shell. `'-U username'` is a single argument that is not a valid argument of `ps`

Comment: Thank you! It's working. I didn't know I can call the `execl` function this way.

Comment: You are welcome. Do not forget to validate the answer if it is ok.

Comment: This doesn't answer the first part of the question: *"Why is this happening"*

Comment: It's happening because adding a space between arguments is how the shell separates arguments, but when calling a function like `execlp()` in a C program, the space is just considered a part of the one arg. In the call, *every* argument needs to be a separated, which is why calling it as `execlp(..., "-U", "username",...)` works but `"-U username"` doesn't.